# AttributeError: 'X' object has no attribute 'Y' in Visual Studio but working fine in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio, jupyter

very new to Python. I'm trying to make a class with a simple method that increases the instance's salary. When I write and run this code in Jupyter notebook, it works fine, but not in Visual Studio. Here's the code:

```
class Employee():
    def __init__ (self,first_name,last_name,pay):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first_name + "." + last_name + "@company.com"

    def fullname(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay = int(self.pay*1.04)

employee_1.pay = 50000
print (employee_1.pay)
employee_1.apply_raise()
print (employee_1.pay)
```

The output from Jupyter as expected:
50000
52000

From VS:

```
>>> employee_1.apply_raise()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Employee' object has no attribute 'apply_raise'
>>> print (employee_1.pay)
50000
```

A similar issue is happening with another code where I objectively define the employees' emails, but VS says these variables are not defined (which leads me to think - could it be I messed up configuring VS?):

```
Employee_1.first_name = "John"
Employee_1.last_name = "Doe"
Employee_1.email = "john.doe@company.com"
Employee_1.pay = 50000

Employee_2.first_name = "Test"
Employee_2.last_name = "User"
Employee_2.email = "test.user@company.com"
Employee_2.pay = 60000

print(Employee_1.email)
print(Employee_2.email)
```

Output from Jupyter:

```
john.doe@company.com
test.user@company.com
```

From VS:

```
NameError: name 'Employee_1' is not defined
>>> print(Employee_2.email)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Employee_2' is not defined
```

Comment: its a bit unclear how you are using VS code?  are you using notebooks in VS code or just entering the python and trying to run it directly?

Comment: In the first code sample, you refer to a variable `employee_1` without ever _defining_ it.  Presumably you have code (that you didn't include in your post) that looks something like this `employee_1 = Employee("John", "Doe", 5000)`.  It's very hard for us to help when you don't show the whole code.

Comment: Guys, thank you both for the help, it really came down to be being a noob, I had copied code, ran it, then deleted it in VS in the hope it would be erased from the "page" (page? dont know the terminology) I was working on, but it had an impact still in the upcoming code.

Also, I was running it in VS with commands like Shift+Enter as if it was Jupyter Notebook (which I was used to).

Answer (score 0):

I was using VS as if it was Jupyter Notebook and running the same shortcuts to run the code (ex. Shift + Enter to run a cell), don't do that apparently. Run instead in the "play" triangle in the top corner each line of code.
Also, don't run lines of code and then delete them and run other lines on top of that, you might think you deleted code with no impact, it's not true.
Know it's a basic silly question but just starting here.

Solution as mentioned by LhasaDad - I had defined employees variables in Jupyter but not in VS that's why the code was running in one but not in the other.

Comment: glad you were able to figure it out.  maybe give an upvote on the comments (little upward triangle next to them to let folks know the comment helped.

Comment: @LhasaDad Note that upvoting comments requires 15 reputation points (I think).

Comment: @AdrianMole Good point.